# Bind Angular FormGroup to Chartjs data

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

In my sample `doughnutChartData` contain a array copy of data initialized in `formGenerator`. I want use angular binding. if I change my form, I want change my doughnut chart dynamicly.

**HTML template:**

```
<canvas baseChart
          [data]="doughnutChartData"
          [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
          [chartType]="doughnutChartType"></canvas>
```

**Angular component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generator',
  templateUrl: './generator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generator.component.scss']
})
export class GeneratorComponent implements OnInit {

  public doughnutChartLabels = ['foo', 'bar'];
  public doughnutChartData = [30, 15];
  public doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';
  formGenerator: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGenerator = this.formBuilder.group({
      sequenceNumberTime: 30,
      sequenceLetterTime: 15
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I try this but do not work:

```
this.doughnutChartData = [this.formGenerator.controls.sequenceNumberTime.value, this.formGenerator.controls.sequenceLetterTime.value];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.formGenerator.valueChanges.subscribe(val => { ... });`

**Full code:**

```
export class GeneratorComponent {

  public doughnutChartLabels = ['foo', 'bar'];
  public doughnutChartData;
  public doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';
  formGenerator: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.doughnutChartData = [30, 15];
    this.formGenerator = this.formBuilder.group({
      sequenceNumberTime: 30,
      sequenceLetterTime: 15
    });
    this.formGenerator.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.doughnutChartData = [val.sequenceNumberTime, val.sequenceLetterTime];
    });
  }

}
```